# Split field when deserializing JSON object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have this in JSON (data changed to protect the guilty):

```
    {"members" : [{"Name":"Mick Jagger","Status":"ACTIVE","ExpireDate":"11/19/2015","TermType":"MONTH","State":"NY","Address2":"","Address1":"123 Anystreet","Type":"PREMIUM","EmailAddress":"mick.jagger@stickyfingers.com","Zip":"12345","Country":"US","City":"New York","Term":"12"},
{"Name":"Keith Richards","Status":"ACTIVE","ExpireDate":"11/19/2015","TermType":"ANNUAL","State":"CT","Address2":"","Address1":"5150 Main St","Type":"PREMIUM","EmailAddress":"keef@xpensivewinos.net","Zip":"45678","Country":"US","City":"New York","Term":"1"}]}
```

And I have this class:

```
public class Member
{
    public string Company_Num { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string  ExpireDate { get; set; }
    public string TermType { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Term { get; set; }
}

public class MemberList
{
    public List<Member> members { get; set; }
}
```

When I deserialize this into a dataset, it works beautifully. But...

When I generated the MemberList class, I forgot that "Name" in JSON needs to be split into FirstName and LastName. Is there a way to deserialize the JSON object and split "Name" at the same time? (So FirstName is "Keith", LastName is "Richards" and so on.)

Here's how it looks when I deserialize it to MemberList:

```
public static MemberList memList()
    {            
        WebClient atv = new WebClient();
        var data = atv.DownloadString("https://www.somewebsvc.com/memberships");
        MemberList m = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MemberList>(data);
        return m;
    }
```

Comment: How will you split names with multiple words? I think you should reconsider splitting them

Comment: We've already settled on how that will be handled. I'm not happy with it, but that's how the client wants it.

Comment: You can create two fields and in the getter just split the `Name` anyhow you want

Comment: Yep. Once I put the new field in, the foreach loop just sort of wrote itself. Nothing like a little public groveling to jog one's brain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case of figuring it out as soon as you ask the question.

I added a Name property to Members then added a foreach loop before the code returns the list. So now it looks like this:

```
public static MemberList memList()
{            
    WebClient atv = new WebClient();
    var data = atv.DownloadString("https://www.somewebsvc.com/memberships");
    MemberList m = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MemberList>(data);
    foreach (Member mb in m.members)
        {
            string[] names = mb.Name.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 2);
            mb.FirstName = names[0];
            mb.LastName = names[1];
        }
    return m;
}
```

As was pointed out in the comments, it's pretty ugly when you have to parse "Mary Ann Smith" or "Nigel Baxter Taylor", but you can pretty much insert any string-parsing logic in there and it'll work. The client just wants the first word of the name for first name. If that makes them happy, I'm not going to argue.

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution would be to make fields in your model that will return desired values on getting them:

```
public class Member
{
     //other properties
     private string _lastName;
     public string LastName {get 
     {
       if (_lastName == null)
           _lastName = Name.Split(new [] {' '}, 2)[1];
       return _lastName;
     }}

     private string _firstName;
     public string FirstName {get 
     {
        if (_firstName== null)
           _firstName= Name.Split(new [] {' '}, 2)[0];
       return _firstName;
     }}
}
```

Comment: Or similarly make a Name property that is actually a front-end to FirstName and LastName member variables. JSON deserialization will invoke its setter.